# ag-grid createRangeChart Line start from 0

Tags: ag-grid

I use createRangeChart to the line but i want that range wii start at 0 ,but i can't set lineDashOffset to anywhere
how can i use lineDashOffset in createRangeChart ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcRox.png)

I want 30.6 that one start to 0

```
onFirstDataRendered: function onFirstDataRendered(params) {
const colIds = params.columnApi
            .getAllDisplayedColumns()
            .map(col => col.getColId());
params.api.createRangeChart({
    chartType: 'line',
    // chartThemeOverrides: {
    //     common: {
    //         title: {
    //             enabled: true,
    //             text: message,
    //         },
    // },
    cellRange: {
        columns: colIds,
    },
    suppressChartRanges: false,
    chartContainer: document.querySelector("#datalistgridChart"+id),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i find min can set 0 in the
createRangeChart -> chartThemeOverrides -> cartesian -> axes -> number -> min:0

```
    params.api.createRangeChart({
                    chartType: chartType,
                    chartThemeOverrides: {
                        cartesian: {
                            axes: {
                                number: {
                                    label: {
                                        formatter: (params) => {
                                            if (chartType == 'line'){
                                                return params.value+'%';
                                            }
                                            return params.value;
                                        }
                                    },
                                    min:0,
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        common: {
                            legend: {
                                enabled: true,
                                position: 'bottom',
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    unlinkChart: true,
                    cellRange: {
                        columns: colIds,
                    },
                    seriesChartTypes:seriesChartTypes,
                    suppressChartRanges: false,
                    chartContainer: document.querySelector("#datalistgridChart"+id),
                });
```